# Generalization of Brownian motion to $\alpha$-stable distributions

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stable-distribution

Brownian motion is constructed as a limit of the sum i.i.d. Gaussian increments. Can one use a non-Gaussian $\alpha$-stable distribution (e.g. the Cauchy distribution) instead, and still construct a process? Would the scale parameter of such process evolve according to the formula $c_t = t^{1/\alpha}$?

Comment: An even wider generalisation are [Lévy processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process). Given that "The probability distributions of the increments of any Lévy process are infinitely divisible" and the family of $\alpha-$stable distributions is a well-known class of [infinitely divisible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_%28probability%29) distributions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My quick answer would be yes, but I am not sure about the scale parameter. You can view a Gaussian random walk as a subset of random walks with stable distributions.  All stable distributions have the property that a linear combination of two i.i.d. stable distributions is also stable. (All this is related to a generalized central limit theore and functional analysis, but that's too much to deal with here.)

Comment: I should add that John Nolan was writing a book on stable distributions that was going to include a chapter on Stable RWs. His webpage might be useful: http://academic2.american.edu/~jpnolan/stable/stable.html